# Using RSS <cloud> element to ping google

Tags: html, wordpress, rss

Today when browsing RSS 2.0 information I found out a element `<cloud>` which can notify services like search engines of update of feed.

On w3schools the code is like this:

```
<cloud domain="www.w3schools.com" port="80" path="/RPC"
  registerProcedure="NotifyMe" protocol="xml-rpc" />
```

Further I found out that you can ping google of sitemap update(remember they consider RSS Feeds to be submited as sitemap) using this link.

```
http://www.google.com/webmasters/sitemaps/ping?sitemap=url
```

So can i use the code above changing the values to google domain and get that to ping google. I searched on google but can't find anything related to this.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS_Cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google [recommends](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.fr/2014/10/best-practices-for-xml-sitemaps-rssatom.html) that you use [PubSubHubbub](http://pubsubhubbub.superfeedr.com/) to ping them for updated content.

It's a fairly simple protocol to implement and relativeley similar to how RSSCloud works.